# image Height from position absolute div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello im trying to get image height from an position absolute image but if i try to get the image value outside of the function it returns 0?

http://jsfiddle.net/vvorqo2c/4/

```
console.log($('.inner-slider .active img').height());
```

Answer (score 4):

You should wait for the image to load. Here is a quick example.

```
$('img').on('load', function() {
   console.log($(this).height());
});
```

Comment: when im using bind it never fires the functions.

Comment: seem weird both those function only take the height value of generated img but doesn't take height of the main images.